# Refresh android assets after expo eject in react native app

Tags: react-native

I have existing project writing on react-native, and these project has native module, that is why  these project have android folder (was executed command expo eject with expoKit enabled)
But, after refresh icons in asset folder, these images doesn't upgrade in android app folder.
How i can refresh assets directory after changing assets in mail folder?

-- UPDATE ---

I fix these problem: after changing expo source, you must execute command: expo publish.

Comment: I am so sorry I cannot understand what this question is about and why this is a programming question. Could you provide a some more specifics please?

Comment: @Owl He meant that assets like images, fonts and icons were not getting loaded after ejecting from expo generated react-native app, `expo publish` is required to bundle assets and generate app release build afterward with it.